# highcharts unable to select certain classes

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to select specific elements in order to change the 'stroke' attribute (to change the color).

Strangely, I can select some elements by class, but the one I really need to change, does not appear to be selectable and I can't figure out why.

In the code, there are 3 selections that, currently, simply output the number of elements found and writes that number into a

tag.

The 'g.highcharts-button rect' works and writes the appropriate value into the  tag.

However, the class I really need to be able to select, 'highcharts-label-box', seems impossible to select.

If anyone could tell me how to select this element I then need to be able to change the 'stroke' attribute to a value of '#ff0000.

I've spent several days on this and I just cannot see how to do this, or why it won't work. Help!

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markh/x2vdpt78/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
        <title>Total Asset Allocation</title>         
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>         
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
        <script>
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    "chart": {
        renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'area',
    marginBottom: 150,
    events: {
      load: function() {
/*
    THE NEXT FEW LINES OF CODE (CURRENTLY COMMENTED OUT) ARE MY ATTEMPT
    TO SELECT SPECIFIC CLASSES. AT THE MOMENT, I'M ONLY TRYING TO COUNT
    THE FOUND CLASSES AND OUTPUT THEM TO A <p> TAG FOR DEBUGGING.

          var g = document.querySelectorAll("g.highcharts-button rect");
            document.getElementById("gs").innerHTML = 'gs=' + g.length;

          var w = document.querySelectorAll("path.highcharts-label-box");
          document.getElementById("ws").innerHTML = 'ws=' + w.length;

          var p = document.querySelectorAll('svg g path.highcharts-label-box');
            document.getElementById("ps").innerHTML = 'ps=' + p.length;
*/

          var locator = document.querySelector('.highcharts-exporting-group');
            $(locator).append($('.highcharts-plot-lines-0').detach());

          this.renderer.rect(this.plotLeft, this.plotSizeY + this.plotTop + 100, this.plotSizeX, 2)
          .css({
            fill: '#000',
            zIndex: 4
          }).add();

        this.renderer.rect(this.plotSizeX / 16 * 9.5 + this.plotLeft, this.plotSizeY + this.plotTop + 100 - 5, 2, 12)
          .css({
            fill: '#000',
            zIndex: 4
          }).add();

        this.renderer.text('Years to Retirement', 250, 480)
          .css({
            fontSize: 15
          }).add();

        this.renderer.text('Years Past Retirement', 550, 480)
          .css({
            fontSize: 15
          }).add();

        this.renderer.text("\u25b6", this.chartWidth - 21, 467)
          .css({
            fontSize: 15
          }).add();

        this.renderer.text('\u2B07', 650, 400)
          .css({
            fontSize: 10
          }).add();

        this.renderer.text('MM RetireSMART<br/><span style="color:transparent">...</span>"In Retirement', 615, 414)
          .css({
            fontSize: 10
          }).add();
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Target Asset Allocation'
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['45+', 40, 35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, '30+'],
    tickColor: '#000',
    tickWidth: 1,
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    title: {
      enabled: false
    },

    plotLines: [{
      color: '#fff',
      width: 5,
      visible: true,
      value: 9
    }]
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Weighting',
      style: {
        color: '#000',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
    },
    label: {
      padding: 50
    },
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    tickInterval: 10,
    tickLength: 5,
    tickWidth: 1,
    tickColor: '#000',
    "allowDecimals": false,
    gridLineWidth: 0
  },
  plotOptions: {
    area: {
      stacking: 'percent',
      lineColor: '#fff',
      lineWidth: 1,
      marker: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        lineColor: '#fff'
      }
    },
    series: {
      events: {
        afterAnimate: function() {
          var label = this.labelBySeries;
          label.attr({
            'text-anchor': 'middle',
          }).css({
            color: this.options.labelColor
          })
        }
      },
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
    }
  },
  series: [{
    useHTML: true,
    name: '<span style="color: transparent;">WWWWWWW</span>Other Funds</span>',
    color: '#b0b0b0',
    label: {
      connectorAllowed: true,
      onArea: false,
      style: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: 'large'
      }
    },
    data: [2, 3, 3, 4.5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 5, 3.5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4]
  }, {
    name: '<span style="color: transparent;">WWW</span>Fixed Income<br><span style="color:transparent;font-size:3px;">W</span><br/><span style="color: transparent;">WWW</span>Funds',
    color: '#010101',
    label: {
      style: {
        fontSize: 'large'
      }
    },
    data: [5, 6, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14, 16, 16, 18, 19, 30, 35, 44, 55, 66]
  }, {
    name: '<span class="EquityFunds">Equity Funds</span><span style="color: transparent;">WW</span>',
    color: '#303030',
    label: {
      style: {
        fontSize: 'large'
      }
    },
    data: [95, 99, 98, 97.5, 90, 80, 70, 60, 40, 33, 22, 20, 17, 15, 13, 11]
  }],

});

});
    </script>         
    </head>     
    <body> 
        <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 510px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        <p id="gs"></p>
        <p id="ws"></p>
        <p id="ps"></p>
    </body>     
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply change stroke attribute in series.afterAnimate event:

```
label.box.attr({
            stroke: 'red'
          })
```

The only problem was to find an object (box) that contains connector attributes.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/45hfga0y/

Also, you can do it using your approach. We can get an element with selector path.highcharts-label-box and set attribute like this:

```
var w = document.querySelectorAll("path.highcharts-label-box");
               w[0].setAttribute('stroke', 'red');
```

But we have to get w element after animate is finished - otherwise, if we do this in chart.load event, the w element will not exist yet.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5q7feort/

Hope it helps!

Best regards

ps. please, as daniel_s told you before, do not duplicate your questions on a few support channels. You will get your answer anyway.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you very much.  Sorry for duplicate posting - I was getting desperate. Won't do it again.